# Is the general behavior of Flushable.flush() to block until the operation is complete?

Tags: java, asynchronous, flush

We have a library which buffers its operations to improve performance. The caller can invoke `flush()` method to force it to start doing its operation.

But right now, the `flush()` method is implemented in such a way that it starts doing its operations asynchronously.

That is, when a caller calls the `flush()` method, it will start doing its operations in a different thread and the `flush()` method just returns.

This way, the caller does NOT know if the operations are complete (they have to find it out by checking the results of the operation) or not before calling the `close()` method.

I wanted to fix it by making the `flush()` call block until all the operations are complete.

Before doing so, I wanted to make sure the `flush()` method should block. But the API documentation doesn't specify a contract like that.

[`Flushable.flush()` API Doc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Flushable.html#flush())

> Flushes this stream by writing any buffered output to the underlying stream.

[`OutputStream.flush()` API Doc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush())

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by
>   the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended destination.
>
> If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided
>   by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing
>   the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream
>   are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee
>   that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk
>   drive.
>
> The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.

Neither of the docs specify anything about blocking until the output is written or not.

But what is the general understanding of `flush()`, should it be a blocking call or not?

Comment: Please try to taper off the bold-face. It's just noise. It doesn't add anything, and it hinders readability.

Comment: As `OutputStream.flush()` doesn't guarantee data to be physically saved, it does guarantee that they are written to underlying stream, and such guarantee cannot be given without blocking. Typically `flush()` blocks, so IMO your fix would make the API follow expectations of most programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the API documentation doesn't specify a contract like that.

Yes it does.

Both the Javadoc quotations are from the `OutputStream` family, which is inherently blocking for all operations. You can't 'guarantee that bytes previously written to the stream are flushed' if you do it asynchronously.

Solution: don't.

Comment: I hope by "Solution: don't.", you meant to not do flush() asynchronously.

Comment: @Codebender Correct.